# Windows Word License for Mac Windows

Tags: ms-office

Will my Office for windows license work for office on mac? I don't think it will, but I was just checking.

Comment: I don't believe there is a cross-transferable option. You are much better off asking this question on Microsoft Office's forums. BOL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your Windows license for Office will not work with the Mac version of Office. According to [this post on a Microsoft support forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macstart/transferring-microsoft-office-2010-license-from-pc/335e7518-5f8c-46ae-a77c-a1d3bd60e2b3):

> Mac Office (2011) is licensed as a completely separate product & is produced specifically for the Mac OS. If you choose to use it you will have to purchase it outright - there is no 'transfer' of a license from one OS to another.